# Skip NULL and show only unique value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to call the Web API from Angular application and show the results in the two dropdowns. I have below code, where I am trying to show only the unique values in the dropdown and without any NULL

```
 service.get<ShipmentByProject[]>(this.entityUrl).subscribe(x => {this.ShipmentList = x});

  for(let i=0; i< this.ShipmentList.length; i++) {
    if( flags[this.ShipmentList[i].customer_shipto_name]) continue;
    flags[this.ShipmentList[i].customer_shipto_name] = true;
    this.shipTo.push(this.ShipmentList[i].customer_shipto_name);
  }
```

[image]

With in the for loop for getting the unique values and it works when I tried to remove the NULL and changed the if condition to

```
   if( (flags[this.ShipmentList[i].customer_shipto_name] || this.ShipmentList[i].customer_shipto_name)) continue;
```

For the above code it returns no data back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove NULL values by using this:

```
this.shipTo = this.ShipmentList.filter(_ => _.customer_shipto_name);
```

and then use new Set() to get only unique values:

```
const uniqueValues = new Set(this.shipTo);
```

Comment: Do I use 'this.shipTo = this.ShipmentList.filter(_ => _.customer_shipto_name);' inside the for loop?